# Matplotlib Wedge artists in legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am generating a plot with a collection of wedges using matplotlib.patches.Wedge(). The wedges are different colors and with different angles subtended. I would like to include Wedge artists in a legend, but the following MWE is resulting in Line artists in the legend instead of Wedge artists.

[legend() docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html) show examples for Line2D and Patch artists. How can I include Wedge artists in my legend?

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Wedge
from matplotlib import rc

plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor']='#EEEEEE'
plt.rcParams['savefig.facecolor']='#EEEEEE'

colors = ['#e41a1c','#377eb8','#4daf4a','#984ea3']
          
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 3))
ax = fig1.gca().axes
radius = 0.5
legend_elements = [Wedge((0, 1), radius, 0, 90, width=radius, color=colors[0], label='category1'),
                   Wedge((0, 1), radius, 0, 180, width=radius, color=colors[1], label='category2'),
                   Wedge((0, 1), radius, 0, 270, width=radius, color=colors[2], label='category3'),
                   Wedge((0, 1), radius, 0, 360, width=radius, color=colors[3], label='category4')]
ax.legend(handles = legend_elements, loc='lower center',
          bbox_to_anchor= (0.5, 1.01), ncol=4,
          borderaxespad=0, frameon=False)
fig1.show()
```

Comment: You want the entries in the legend to have the same shapes as the wedges you created?

Comment: Yes. I want to have example shaped/colored wedges in the legend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create your own `Handler` that tells `matplotlib` how to take a specific `Artist` and transform it to appear in a legend. Often times things need to be resized or transformed in some manner to appear better on a legend.

To create a handler, all you need to do is create any Python object that defines a `legend_artist` method and has the same call signature as below [see docs for more info](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#implementing-a-custom-legend-handler).

From there we simply create a dummy `Wedge` object whose radius is smaller than the box it's being drawn in (hence `min(width, height)`). We update the aesthetic properties on this new dummy wedge based on the inputted `Artists`.

Finally we add the newly created/updated dummy `Wedge` to the `handlebox` to be drawn later.

With the `Handler` out of the way, we now supply a `handler_map` to the call of `ax.legend`. This is essentially a dictionary that maps an `Artist` (in this case `Wedge`) to the `Handler` we just created, essentially tying the artist to the instructions on how to represent it in a legend.

```py
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Wedge
from matplotlib import rc

plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor']='#EEEEEE'
plt.rcParams['savefig.facecolor']='#EEEEEE'

class WedgeHandler:
    def legend_artist(self, legend, orig_handle, fontsize, handlebox):
        x0, y0 = handlebox.xdescent, handlebox.ydescent
        width, height = handlebox.width, handlebox.height
        
        handle = Wedge((0, 0), min(width, height), orig_handle.theta1, orig_handle.theta2)
        handle.update_from(orig_handle)
        handlebox.add_artist(handle)

        return handle


colors = ['#e41a1c','#377eb8','#4daf4a','#984ea3']
          
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 3))
ax = fig1.gca().axes
radius = 0.5
legend_elements = [Wedge((0, 1), radius, 0, 90, width=radius, color=colors[0], label='category1'),
                   Wedge((0, 1), radius, 0, 180, width=radius, color=colors[1], label='category2'),
                   Wedge((0, 1), radius, 0, 270, width=radius, color=colors[2], label='category3'),
                   Wedge((0, 1), radius, 0, 360, width=radius, color=colors[3], label='category4')]
ax.legend(handles = legend_elements, loc='lower center',
          bbox_to_anchor= (0.5, 1.05), ncol=4,
          borderaxespad=0, frameon=False,
          handler_map={Wedge: WedgeHandler()}
         )

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

update, you may run into some issues if you use `Artist.update_from` as it copies over a few too many properties. Instead you can manually specify which properties you want copied using this as an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Wedge
from matplotlib import rc

class WedgeHandler:
    def legend_artist(self, legend, orig_handle, fontsize, handlebox):
        x0, y0 = handlebox.xdescent, handlebox.ydescent
        width, height = handlebox.width, handlebox.height
        r = min(width, height)
        
        handle = Wedge(
            center=(x0 + width / 2, y0 + height / 2),      # centers handle in handlebox
            r=r,                                           # ensures radius fits in handlebox
            width=r * (orig_handle.width / orig_handle.r), # preserves original radius/width ratio
            theta1=orig_handle.theta1,                     # copies the following parameters
            theta2=orig_handle.theta2,
            color=orig_handle.get_facecolor(),
            transform=handlebox.get_transform(),           # use handlebox coordinate system
        )
                        
        handlebox.add_artist(handle)
        return handle

plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor']='#EEEEEE'
plt.rcParams['savefig.facecolor']='#EEEEEE'

colors = ['#e41a1c','#377eb8','#4daf4a','#984ea3']
theta2 = [90, 180, 270, 360]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i, (color, t2) in enumerate(zip(colors, theta2), start=1):
    wedge = Wedge((i, .5), 0.25, theta1=0, theta2=t2, width=0.25, color=color, label=f'category{i}')
    ax.add_artist(wedge)

ax.set_xlim(1-.25, i + .25)
    
legend = ax.legend(title='Default Handler', loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1))
ax.add_artist(legend)

ax.legend(title='Custom Handler', loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 0.5), handler_map={Wedge: WedgeHandler()})
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, nice solution! I'm going to implement this WedgeHandler() class to see if it will work for my application and, most likely, come back to accept your answer shortly.